# How to get JSHint smarttabs option working in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, jshint

I'm trying to configure this using nodejs, without success.
I know that a have to set this option to false, but where? what file?

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461291/how-to-get-jshint-smarttabs-option-working-in-sublime-text-2?rq=1)? It appears to be identical to yours but for ST2. Probably worth a try.

Comment: Yes, i did. They teach how to use sublime to convert tabs to space and reindent. I need to remove the warning message.